# Android | How to use ExpandableListView in a ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have two `ExpandableListViews` in my xml-file and some `TextViews`. When I expand the first (at the top) `ExpandableListView` it squeezes all content below together and the second (at the bottom) `ExpandableListView` has only very less space left. The user can only see the content of the second `ExpandableListView` by scrolling in a very little range.

I already thought of wrapping it in a `ScrollView` but then my `ExpandableListViews` only show the first group and aren't expandable. Also if I set the height to a static number and all groups have been expanded the content can't be seen anymore.

I want that both `ExpandableListViews` can expand and that I can scroll the layout up and down so that everything has enough space.
Any advice?

**My XML.File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Group1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Attention1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/elv_theorie"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="Group2"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Attention2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"/>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/elv_pruefung"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My problem:**

[image: My Problem]

**With a `ScrollView`:** Only first group is shown and it can't be expanded

[image: With ScrollView]

Comment: You better **not**. Nested scrollable Views will most likely cause scrolling issues.

Comment: By default Keep the first groupview expanded  in both Expandable list adapter.

Answer (score 2):

```
Add this line inside the scrollview:
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set dynamic Height of expandable listview using this function

```
private void setListViewHeight(ExpandableListView listView,
                               int group) {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter = (ExpandableListAdapter) listView.getExpandableListAdapter();
    int totalHeight = 0;
    int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
            View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++) {
        View groupItem = listAdapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, listView);
        groupItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        totalHeight += groupItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (((listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i != group))
                || ((!listView.isGroupExpanded(i)) && (i == group))) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listAdapter.getChildrenCount(i); j++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getChildView(i, j, false, null,
                        listView);
                listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        }
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    int height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getGroupCount() - 1));
    if (height < 10)
        height = 200;
    params.height = height;
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();

}
```

Comment: This is very good. But when I expand a group, it doesn't change the height.